# vscode import could not be resolved python

Tags: python, pipenv

I am not sure if it is python or vscode but I added `email_validator` library using command

`pipenv install email_validator`

I can see the file in `pipfile` i.e

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
fastapi = "*"
sqlmodel = "*"
uvicorn = "*"
asyncpg = "*"
greenlet = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
email-validator = "*"

[dev-packages]
black = "*"
pylint = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

but when I import it using this

```
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
```

VS code complains

> Import "email_validator" could not be resolved

In NodeJs, I could confirm if the library is actually imported by looking at node_modules, is there equivalent of that in python?

Comment: Have you tried running the code? If it runs, it's properly installed. I usually have to restart either vscode or the python language server for it to pick up newly installed packages.

Comment: Project runs, restarting laptop/vs-code doesn't fixes it.

Comment: Have you selected the right python interpreter in vscode?

Answer (score 0):

I asked pipenv for the path to my venv folder:

`pipenv --venv`

Then in VS Code, I did `Ctrl-Shift-P`, `Python: Select Interpreter`, and entered the path to my venv.