# Import could not be resolved for modules in same folder

Tags: python, pylance

I have two .py files (modules). I'm trying to import one into the other:

```
from place import Place
```

`place` is the name of the .py files and `Place` name of the class inside it. I am getting an error:

> Import "place" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

I have Python installed correctly and modules are both in the same folder. Answers tried:

- [how do I solve the Pylance(reportMissingImports)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72019083/16222937) (checking environment/interpreter).
- [VS/Pylance warning: import "module" could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887729/vs-pylance-warning-import-module-could-not-be-resolved) (check environment).
- [vscode import could not be resolved python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74539519/vscode-import-could-not-be-resolved-python) (restart Visual Studio Code).

file_to_do_import.py:

```
from place import Place
```

place.py:

```
class Place:
    def __init__(self, place_name, place_address, num_days, total_cost):
        # Instance variables for each book instance!!!!
        self.place_name = place_name
        self.place_address = place_address
        self.num_days = num_days
        self.total_cost = total_cost

    def __str__(self):
        # Instance method to return book information as a string!!!!
        return "{} by {}, published in {}".format(self.place_name, self.place_address, self.num_days, self.total_cost)
```

Comment: You can probably ignore the Pylance error to begin with; does your program _run_ successfully?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to mention, no I cannot run the program. I get the following debug error
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'place'

Comment: Then I'd make extra double sure that you actually do have `place.py`. (You could try to create a new file called `place.py`; if that succeeds, then you didn't have one...)

Comment: I definitely do. "place.py" but I've just realised that the sub-folder has a spacing in the name, does that affect python when its trying to look for another file in its directory?

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1).  Add a `__init__.py` in your directory to make your directory a module.

2).  Use `from .place import Place`

Comment: neither seem to work for me

Comment: So, you have a project directory with 3 files:  __ init __.py, place.py, file_to_do_import.py?  In your `file_to_do_import.py`, you `from .place import Place`, and you get the import error?  Check that your 'class Place(object)' is not indented at all or inside another class?

Comment: ok yep so I've got: 
__init__.py, 
place.py,
file_to_do_import.py
and I've added the "." to place.
Now I'm getting the same issue in development, but, the following error when I try to run it in debug:
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package. Also there's no indent in class object.

Comment: I've added in my code to the original question (how the code was before I asked the question).

Comment: It sounds like python is being executed outside of this path, and doesn't know where that module lives.  You could try to use the parent directory as the package name, for example:  `from parentDirectory.place import Place`.  That could work, but chances are, python doesn't know of that module.  If you are executing python manually, you'll want to add that project path to python.  i.e. `python -m pathToProjectDir <other params>`

Comment: @CloakedArrow `init.py` and `__init__.py` are very different file names.

Comment: ok I'll try this now, I'm executing it through vs codes inbuilt debug terminal

Comment: @MatBailie just tried it without the underscore, still no change.

Comment: It's two underscores, init, two underscores.

Comment: ah I see, yeah I tried that initially, I think SO changed the formatting of what I wrote so it seems like I only typed init

Comment: @AaronPaxson still can't get it to work. Uggh this is frustrating lol. I'm thinking it may be a python configuration issue now idk.